# get data from Console to create log entries for log4net

Tags: c#, .net, log4net, inotifypropertychanged, memorystream

I have some external libraries that I am using that are logging to the console. I want these to log via log4net.

NOTE: I am NOT wanting to log to console from log4net, that should be straight forward.

What I have discovered thus far:

1) Console.setOut method allows using a different file stream.
1.1) Overriding memorystream seemed promising but there isn't a chance for raising an event to notify of changes
2) Writing to a file from Console seems like a work around, where I can read the file to update the UI textbox with new logs
3) FileStreams can autoflush, this means automatic updating of information. This sort of concept is similar to what I am after?

Whats the best way to get the console information put into log4net so that it can publish console log items the same way as log4net is configured? Currently my log4net puts logs into the eventlog, into a databinded wpf textbox, and into a file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally don't know any other solution for this case other then you wrote:

- ovewrite `output` of console pointing it to a file
- read the file and add to a logger

To be notified about the change you can try to use `FileSystemWatcher` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher.aspx.

Or if you don't want "real time notification", canopen file `only for read` and check with the timer if there is any row *after* last saved reader pointer position.

But I think, the first option is much easier.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I was hoping for better news though, haha.